# A C# class with a null namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

While going through some legacy code I discovered that you can declare a C# class without placing it in a namespace (in this scenario I have an ASP.NET WebForms application and some of the web forms are not declared within any namespace).

A `GetType()` on such a class returns a type where the `namespace` property is set to `null`.

I did not know that this was allowed - can anyone suggest why it would be desirable to have a class that is not declared within a namespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It certainly isn't great practice. It *does* makes some examples easier, like "hello world" - maybe the C# designers were going for code-golf ;p

But yes, it is an oddity. I'm not aware of any resounding reason that we *need* to be able to directly use the global namespace. Even for extension methods I'd rather add a `using` directive to bring them in...

Interestingly - there seem to be 40-odd such in `mscorlib.dll` and 20-odd in `system.dll`

```
var mscorlib = typeof(string).Assembly.GetTypes()
   .Where(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Namespace)).ToList();
var system = typeof(Uri).Assembly.GetTypes()
   .Where(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Namespace)).ToList();
```

(but all private / compiler-generated)

Comment: The one rationale I could think of was for making simple examples simpler. But the concept of a namespace is pretty simple itself, and a fairly fundamental one too...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps to allow interoperability with languages that do not support namespaces.

**Update**

After a little spelunking I can see a case that MS use.

All .Net Framework assemblies have some standard classes in the global namespace e.g.

- FXAssembly: version info.
- ThisAssembly: assembly info.
- AssemblyRef: dependent assembly info.

These classes contain canned meta-data which would otherwise be more difficult\expensive to get at. I'm guessing that they chose to locate these in the global namespace so that it would be a standard\conventional location where tools\utilities\etc could get at them. This information is bootstrapping\meta information so logically sits above the concept of namespaces.

Comment: It seems possible, but I can't help thinking that any such language would be pretty crippled when talking to the BCL